# Shake build capturing directories

Tags: shake-build-system

I have recently converted my works make based build system to shake. I am now trying to make shake a little more robust to changes in the directory structure so that I do not have to regenerate the build system.

Each of my projects use are C based and have the following directory structure

- src

  - source folder 1
  - source folder 2
- inc

  - inc folder 1
  - inc folder 2

I am able to capture all the source files but what I cant get to work is capturing the include folders. The root inc folder and the sub folders I am trying to capture into a variable in the build system. I have been using the following setup

```
includes = getDirectoryDir "inc"
```

This will give me the included sub folders but not the root folder inc. Which I thought I could work around but inc will not be tracked.

What I would like is to have something like

```
includes = getDirectoryDirAndRoot "inc"
```

Which will capture each of the subdirectories and the root directory and have them tracked in the build system.

That aside what I have also tried to use

```
gcc -o out includes
```

But I would need to have every element in includes prepended with "-I" which I can't seem to figure out.

I guess how would one go abut doing this in shake, in make I can accomplish all of this by using makes shell function and a couple of string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question can be interpreted both ways, and both ways are useful (you may even want both), so I'll give two answers:

**Answer 1:** You want the C file to be recompiled if any file in the `inc` directory changes.

`"*.c" *> \out -> do
    headerFiles <- getDirectoryFiles "inc" "**/*.h"
    need headerFiles
    ...`

This snippet gets a list of all header files in the `inc` directory (or it's subdirectories) and introduces a dependency on them. If any header file changes, this rule will rerun.

**Answer 2:** You want to get the list of directories to pass to `gcc`.

`"*.c" *> \out -> do
    includeDirs <- getDirectoryDirs "inc"
    cmd "gcc -c" [out] "-Iinc" (map ("-Iinc/" ++) includeDirs)
    ...`

This snippet gets the directory names under `inc` and then uses `map` to prepend `-Iinc/` over them. It also passes `-Iinc` directly. If the list of directories under `inc` changes this rule will rebuild. However, if the header files contained in those directories change nothing will rebuild. You can add dependencies on the used header files with the `gcc -MD` family of flags, as described in the [Shake user manual](https://shakebuild.com/manual), or using the technique from Answer 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [addOracle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.16.4/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:addOracle) and its cousin `addOracleCache`. This should allow you to depend on information besides the files themselves, such as directories to be included.

> But I would need to have every element in includes prepended with "-I" which I can't seem to figure out.

You can use Haskell here. If you have a list of directories `directories :: [FilePath]`, you can turn those into compiler flags with

```
asIncludes :: [FilePath] -> [String]
asIncludes = fmap ("I" ++)
```